# Use glob ** to match file extensions based on recursive parameter

Tags: python, recursion, filesystems, glob

I'm trying to match files with a given extension using a glob pattern.  The glob function (from glob module) has a parameter 'recursive', which seems like it should turn on or off searching subdirectories.  However, I've been unable to construct a glob pattern which will match files of a type in the current directory only if recursive=False and in subdirectories too if recursive=True.

```
folder='C:\\test'
glob(folder+'**.ext',recursive=True) #fails to find any files
glob(folder+'\\**.ext',recursive=True) #fails to search subfolders
glob(folder+'\\**',recursive=True) #fails to filter by type
glob(folder+'\\**\\*.ext',recursive=False) #searches subfolders when it shouldn't
glob(folder+'**\\*.ext',recursive=True) #fails to search subfolders
```

Based on the documentation

> "**" will match any files and zero or more directories

So, I would expect ** to act like * except that it also matches slashes.  However, it isn't working as expected (see the first two examples above).

Why isn't ** working as expected and is there a pattern that will match certain file types and recursion can be switched on or off using only the recursive argument?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have misunderstood the meaning of `recursive=True`. It is used to allow `**` to mean searching subdirectories to a variable depth -- `glob(folder+'\\**\\*.ext',recursive=True)` will find any `*.ext` files in the starting folder or anywhere below it.  Without `recursive=True`, `**` would be interpreted in the normal way, with each `*` meaning to match any number of characters **excluding `\`**, and `**` would therefore just be equivalent to `*` -- in other words `glob(folder+'\\**\\*.ext',recursive=False)` would search for any `*.ext` files that are exactly one level of subdirectory down from the starting folder, but not in the starting folder itself or in deeper subdirectories.

Exactly which you should use will depend on what you are trying to look for -- and it may indeed be that you need to select between different cases with an `if` statement -- but there is no use case for using `**` with `recursive=False`, because it is just equivalent to `*` in that case.

The most likely useful options are:

```
glob(folder+'\\*.ext',recursive=False)  # search in top folder only
glob(folder+'\\*\\*.ext',recursive=False)  # search exactly one level down
glob(folder+'\\**\\*.ext',recursive=True)  # search to arbitrary depth
```

The `,recursive=False` can be omitted because it is the default.

If there were exactly two options that you wanted to select between using a boolean option, you could always write your own wrapper function, for example:

```
def myglob(folder, pattern, subdirs=False):
    if subdirs:
        return glob(f'{folder}\\**\\{pattern}', recursive=True)
    else
        return glob(f'{folder}\\{pattern}')

print(myglob(folder, '*.ext', subdirs=False))
print(myglob(folder, '*.ext', subdirs=True))
print(myglob(folder, '*.ext'))  # same as subdirs=False in this example
```

(In Unix-like operating systems, read `/` for `\` above.)

Comment: Thanks, the thing I still don't get is why don't the first two examples I gave work?  Why can't I do something like the 3rd (which works as expected, toggling based on the value of recursive) while also filtering for a given file extension?

Comment: @KalevMaricq As far as I can tell, it seems that although the `**` with `recursive=True` is intended to match *any number* of path elements, it won't match **parts** of path elements -- so you shouldn't do `**.ext` as part of a glob pattern.

Answer (score 0):

## Operation of glob '**'

The glob source code can be found [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/glob.py).  Other than comments, '**' only appears in the _isrecursive function:

```
def _isrecursive(pattern):
    if isinstance(pattern, bytes):
        return pattern == b'**'
    else:
        return pattern == '**'
```

Because the _isrecursive function checks for '**' using the equality operator, '**' will only operate as intended if it is the entire 'pattern'.  The _isrecursive function is called 4 times in the source code, once for the entire glob and 3 times for 'basename', which is defined as:

```
dirname, basename = os.path.split(pathname)
```

This is called recursively, splitting tails from the path one at a time, and each time, basename is everything following the slash (technically os.sep,which is \ for Windows or / for POSIX).  That means that in order for '**' to operate as described, it **may not be adjacent to anything other than slashes**.

If recursive is not explicitly set to True, '**' = '*'+'*' = '*' since '*' matches 0 or more non-slash characters.

## Matching Extensions

Because of how '**' operates, it must be used to represent an entire level of the glob.  Since it represents *0 or more* levels, r'folder\**\*.ext' *will* match files in 'folder', as well as subfolders.  However, without recursive set to true, this pattern will match only files in the first level of subfolders.

'**.ext' will not work because '**' isn't alone.  This leaves the following options:

1. Use a different library (eg. os.walk, pathlib.glob, etc.)
2. `[f for f in glob(folder+'\\**',recursive=subdirs) if f.endswith('.ext')]`
3. `glob(folder+('\\**' if subdirs else '')+'\\*.ext, recursive=True)`

   Or equivalently,

   ```
   if recursive:
       glob(folder+'\\**\\*.ext', recursive=True)
   else:
       glob(folder+'\\*.ext')
   ```
4. `glob(folder+'\\..\\**\\*.ext', recursive=subdirs) #not recommended since it will also match files in sibling folders`